# Is there a simple way to transform an ordered List into a lookup table?

Tags: java, lookup-tables

If I create a list using `Arrays.asList()`, the list is guaranteed to be allocated in insertion-order. I want to use this as a way to easily define the sort order for a comparator at the top of my class:

```
List<String> sortedKeyOrder = Arrays.asList("x", "y", "z");
```

Is there a simple way to transform the insertion-order of this list into a constant-time lookup table for the comparator?

Comment: You mean something like `indexOf()` but with O(1) time-complexity?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. May add some pseudocode.

Comment: Create a `Map<String, Integer>`. Iterate over the list with a simple for-loop and do `map.put(list.get(i), i)`. And there you go. You can then get the index of the element using `map.get(<element>)`.

Comment: Try a `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static method returning a `Comparator` that is backed by a map like this:

```java
public static <T> Comparator<T> lookupComparator(Iterable<T> order) {
    int index = 0;
    final Map<T, Integer> orderMap = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    for (T t : order) {
        orderMap.put(t, index++);
    }
    return new Comparator<T>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(o1);
            Objects.requireNonNull(o2);
            if (o1 == o2) {
                return 0;
            }
            return orderMap.get(o1).compareTo(orderMap.get(o2));
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void testLookupComparator() {
    Comparator<String> lc = lookupComparator(Arrays.asList("c", "a", "b", "z", "m", "g"));
    List<String> someValues = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "g", "m", "z");
    someValues.sort(lc);
    System.out.println(someValues);
}
```

This will print `[c, a, b, z, m, g]`. However, it will throw an exception, if either value is `null`, or not in the map.

Comment: This is correct, upvoted. It's enough with a `HashMap`, though. You don't need the `LinkedHashMap`